# Should javascript be included via <script src=""> tags, or included straight into a page template?

Tags: node.js

For a templating system like Jade, is it better to put page-specific (that is, used on only 2-3 pages) javascript in its own `.js` file in a public directory (to be included with a `<script>` tag), or to write it in its own .jade file to be included straight into any html files? I.E., should I do this:

---

`page.jade`

```
script(src="/path/to/file.js")
```

`file.js`

```
$(document).ready(function() { /* do a thing */ });
```

---

or this:

---

`page.jade`

```
block script-file
include scripts/file
```

`scripts/file.jade`

```
block script-file
    script(type="text/javascript").
         $(document).ready(function() { /* Do a thing */ });
```

---

It seems like the second would result in fewer HTTP requests, which is a good thing, right? But then, it seems somewhat outside the intended use case for Jade to be hosting clientside javascript in a serverside template. Which do people use in practice? Which is actually better?